# TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I was working on a simple node project, and I came across this error. I can't seem to find a way through it, nor do I really understands what this means

```
const expect = require('expect');
const request = require('supertest');

const {app} = require('./../server');
const {Todo} = require('./../models/ToDo');

beforeEach((done) => {
    Todo.remove().then(() => done());
}); 

describe('POST /todos', () => {
    it('should create a new todo', (done) => {
        var text = 'Test todo text';

        request(app)
            .post('/todos')
            .send({text})
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect(res.body.text).toBe(text);
            })  
            .end((err, res) => {
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                Todo.find().then((todos) => {
                    expect(todos.length).toBe(1);
                    expect(todos[0].text).toBe(text);
                    done();
                }).catch((e) => done(e));
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post the code of `models/ToDo` module?

Answer (score 0):

The error means your `Todo` is undefined. You can check like this.

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    console.log(Todo); // put a breakpoint here if you want to inspect the variable
    Todo.remove().then(() => done());
});
```